# Impact of low open_files_limit in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

Like many other users, on MySQL startup I get the warning

```
Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 1024 (request: 65000)
```

There are various solution availible, but I can't find a single resource on *why* I bother would fix this. What is the impact of that warning?

Thanks

Comment: One day , if you run part of  your stack in the same box, you will have a fail cuz (for example) php was not able to load your classes as a result of 'too many files open' , at the OS level. Track it and fix it would be my recommendation. I said php, but it could be whatever flavour of stack you are accustomed to.

Answer (score 0):

`open_files_limit = 1024` is not big enough for maybe 1/3 of the systems out there.  This is derived from an OS setting (see `ulimit`) which should be increased.

On the other hand, `table_open_cache = 65000` is excessive.  It is rare to need more than a few thousand.  Too big a number wastes RAM that could be better used for other things.

Will you get into trouble?  Maybe.  But probably not.